# Set child routing in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an app which have different routes like Contact, Login, Edit, etc, here contact route has two child routes Spreadsheet & TwoPanel, both shares common `top-nav`, `top-filters` & many more. So whenever I hit `contact/spreadsheet` all those common components (top-nav, top-filter) gets reload, now if I hit `contact/two-panel` these common components reloads again which should not happen. So how I can prevent this. Below is my code:

```
{ 
    path: 'contact', component: ContactParent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'spreadsheet', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'spreadsheet', component: Spreadsheet },
        { path: 'two-panel', component: TwoPanel }
    ]
},
{ path: 'login', component: Login },
{ path: 'edit', component: EditSingleContact }
```

and here is parent components template:

```
<!-- ContactParent template -->
<top-nav></top-nav>
<top-filter></top-filter>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<cancel-payment></cancel-payment>
<delete-dialog></delete-dialog>
<create-link></create-link>
<message></message>

<!-- main.html -->
<main>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Comment: can u post ContactParent template ?

Comment: @ParthGhiya above template is ContactParent template

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is all wrong for the template

Whichever is your root component, it should contain all this components.
ParentComponent template should only contain router outlet & Directive for ParentComponent should be included in parent.component

example : Suppose this is your app.component.html

```
     <top-nav></top-nav>
     <top-filter></top-filter>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     <cancel-payment></cancel-payment>
     <delete-dialog></delete-dialog>
     <create-link></create-link>
     <message></message>
     <parent-component></parent-component>  //include this Parent component template
```

your parent.component.html should only contain

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This way all the components would be called only once.

Comment: But in this way login page or edit page and other pages will have these common components which are not needed there.

Comment: Yeah but as I mentioned its refreshing all those other components (top-nav, top-filter) whenever I navigate between spreadsheet & two panel

Comment: ok got it theres something as auxillary routes here plunker Link for that:
 
**https://plnkr.co/edit/e5eK0ksB08GXzIRCyInr?p=preview**

try that out, if it helps I will edit the answer & U can accept it

Comment: I am not sure how this will help in my case, can you describe it by using my code?